# Facebook SDK crashes google-play-services-lib if imported as existing Android source code

Tags: java, android, facebook, google-maps

I have an extremely strange problem to which finding solution seems to be very tricky. Here's the story:

The application I'm working on uses both Facebook SDK and Google Maps v2. Team mate was working on Google Maps and I was working on Facebook part. When we combine his and mine code it appears that just having FacebookSDK as an imported project in the workspace (not even referenced in Properties|Android|Library section of our app) , straight away makes the app not see the Google Maps library. The work around is to add Google Maps into Java build path, however the application still crashes when we try to access the activity based on Google Maps. Not having Facebook SDK in the workspace makes the Google Maps work. When the app is ran with Google Maps added to the Java build Path, when trying to access the Google Maps activity LogCat shows NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Hope I explained the problem well. If not then let me know what more is required to get closer to fixing this strange problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: It seems that adding Java Build Path reference to android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google_play_services.jar file fixed the issue. Crysis averted. ;)

Comment: Not working dude.. Please provide a feasible solution.. When I import google-play-service-lib. R.java file gets deleted..