# app R. broken after google play service import

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I imported playservices following the officially documments of android.
Imported the project from sdk-for-windos > extras > google > google-maps-project-lib or so.
Then I add it to my project as a dependency, like i've to do...

But on the moment of importing the lib, all my R. files (Layout / id etc.) Are broken, 
R.android works , just R.myappname is totally broken.... it doesn't regenerated.

I've no idea how, and there is just no info about this issue to find.
All help is appriciated, im desperated! (To add, i want to use googleplayservices for google maps, which seems i've to use this for, if it helps).

Comment: Did You try to clean the project and see errors?

Comment: My app is completely error / warning free. One thing which does seems weird to me is the order private libraries are displayed? I tryed to use the google play service lib in a new project, and it just worked well, but the order of private libraries was something else. In the new project googleservices came before android support library. Does this matther?

Comment: The moment i click properties > android > add library and then apply my the app gets refreshed, generated files are created, but R isn't there. When i remove the library its all fine again. Is it possible a library 'blocks' another library in this case android support lib?

Comment: try to update your sdk and set the api library of Android to 4.2.2

Comment: Everthing is uptodate and building in the last version 4.2.2

Comment: @iLuvCode:: Have u got any solution??

Comment: Nah , just doesn't work for me... I did quit for now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are having the same issue I have encountered. Try this: Add Java Build Path reference to android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google_play_services.jar file. It fixed the issue I had.  [Problem i faced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939201/facebook-sdk-crashes-google-play-services-lib-if-imported-as-existing-android-so/20939462#20939462)

screenshot #1: google_play_services project referenced as a library

[image: google_play_services project referenced as a library]
screenshot #2: google_play_services.jar added to java build path

[image]
screenshot #3: google_play_services.jar ticked on
[image]

Comment: So project > build path > projects tab > add project (play services lib), then go to order and export and tick it? Sorry if i missunderstood your answer, could you please give a example? I didn't really go further in eclipse then was necessary, never faced these problems.

Comment: project->preferences->java build path-> libraries->google_play_services.jar. then once you've done that go to the last tab and tick google_play_services.jar and press ok. Hopefully will work :)

Comment: It works! Adding the google play services in this way instead of android > add library, thnx! (Still have to test further, but it seems to work:)

Comment: Adding this only solves a part, but using this: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> for example in my manifest doesn't work, but this is required. Importing classes are found, but not everthing is found... Adding the project from propeties still causes R. crash

Comment: Have you tried using both ways? My project has the setup as seen on the above screenshots. Both android -> library and java build path ->library ->order and export.

Comment: Yes i've also both, but when importing the library in android > library. R. breaks. Also good to mention maybe that the files of the just imported library , google play services also doesn't generate anything, tryed everthing...

Comment: Btw you do external jar right? Or your selecting the jar from the imported google play service project? Idk if it makes any difference, but i've now to check everthing..

Comment: I know how you feel haha. I had the same problem and just ended up trying everything in hope of getting it to work. I've referenced both from within my sdk folder my path for java build path part is: C:\Users\User\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar and for the android -> library :  C:\Users\User\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Comment: Still none:( This case is still open, and not solved.

Comment: How big is your project? Is it just a tutorial on google play services? You can send me the code if it isn't something commercial and I will give it a go on my machine. Other than that I can't think of anything else D:

Comment: Thnx, i will check in a moment.

Comment: Not working dude.. Please provide a feasible solution.. When I import google-play-service-lib. R.java file gets deleted..